# Sort my Trello cards and lists alphabetically

Tags: trello, sorting

I have an "Active Projects" board on Trello that has about 60 lists in it, each with about 1-4 cards.

I want to sort the 60 lists I have alphabetically rather that assigning them a number placement.

Answer (score 3):

This is not currently possible but there are a lot of comments and votes for this feature here: https://trello.com/c/VWrInnH8